# SQL Server 2008- If date falls on weekend, Increase to next Monday

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, datetime, date-manipulation

In SQL Server I am calculating a date based on certain business rules. If the date falls on a weekend I need to move it up to the next monday...so basically:

```
if(date == saturday)
{
 add 2 days
}
if(date == sunday)
{
  add 2 day
}
```

What is the easiest way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extract it from DateTime.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762911.aspx

Paul

Answer (score 1):

Use `DATENAME` [as per MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174395.aspx).

Example: `select datename(weekday, getdate())` returns Thursday as of today.